# redirecting to url that will never complate

Tags: 7, uri

i used this code to redirect page to another

```
$path=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$new_path= 'http://localhost/mysite/print/194?0=' . $path;
drupal_goto($new_path);
```

but when requesting that page this error show up:

[image]

and the url in the address bar is:
http://localhost/mysite/print/194?0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=0=f1=All&f2[value][year]=&f2[value][month]=
but when i print the $new_path using drupal_set_message the url looks like correct one
Can you help me to solved it? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is that the query string should be passed in separate from the base URL itself, eg, it should be part of the $options array argument to `drupal_goto()`.  Otherwise, as you've noticed, `drupal_goto()` doubles up a lot of times.  If you fix that, I am fairly confident that you will get it to work.

Check out http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7
and
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7 
for more information on this.